# Angular 2 sticky footer impementation

Tags: html, css, angular, sticky-footer

I want my footer to be a sticky footer and tried following the css tricks negative margin trick, but did not work. I tried to impersonate my angular2 app in the below plunker code. I want the sticker not be fixed but sticky and go to the bottom when there are more content available in the main section. Note the footer is displayed above the data in the main section.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WSUC4xLMWH6fY77UyFqI?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

app.component:

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
  <section class="main">
    <div class="main-container">
      Display my router-outlet here          
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        {{ hero }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer-component></footer-component>
```

Any help to fix and move the footer down is appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your goals are, but your styles for class "main" have an absolute position.

Comment: If I remove it, then the text is shown beneath the navbar section. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.  I'm assuming you've tried one of these: [CSS-tricks - Sticky footer, five ways](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

For that to work, you would need to:

- Remove absolute positioning of both the footer and the content.
- Remove default top and bottom margins from body.
- If you are not going with the flexbox or grid option, then place all content except for the footer inside of **one** element *(so you can make sure the total height of that element plus the footer is at least the height of the viewport)*.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/P7D8SjL3CddbJzd58xxH?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts) is an implementation of your Angular2 app with a sticky footer.

The sticky footer is achieved by wrapping all of the main content in a single div and using `calc()` to set it's minimum height to `100vh` minus the footer's height.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want the footer to be fixed but sticky. It should be placed down the page when there is more content. I will update my question.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, although in my real app once I remove `position:absolute` the navbar section is pushed down and app looks clumsy. Guess since there is more to the css used in the real app (grids, etc)

Answer (score 8):

You can still follow this example mentioned by
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Simply add this code to `styles.scss`

```
html, 
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In your `app.component.scss`

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%; // used percent instead of vh due to safari bug.
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

In your `app.component.html`

```
<header>...</header>

<main class="Site-content">..</main>

<footer>...</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I think `app.component.html` should be this way `<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>` can you update the answer to meet this case ?

Comment: Thats one way to do it to. But it is the same thing as the one  i mentioned already. You have just turned header and footer as components.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to make position:absolute for your .main block. Absolute positioning for your footer will be enough.
Try something like this

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
   min-height: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 55px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Also remove margins and padding-top from .main block styles

Comment: Thanks, but if I remove the absolute position from main, then the text is displayed beneath navbar section.

Comment: What text? .main block text. You can remove margin-top and paddint-top from .main block

Comment: Yes, after removing them the top of the main block text goes beneath the navbar section.

Comment: Are you sure you delete position:absolute for .main block? I played around with you plunker and It works for me.

Comment: Yes, I just removed the `position:absolute` from .main css style and the body content `"Display my router here"` went beneath the header.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to edit 2 files:

index.html:

```
 <!-- Full height body -->
    <body class="pt-3 h-100">
<!-- Full height app container, and also use flexbox columns -->
      <app-root class="d-flex flex-column h-100"></app-root>
    </body>
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- Footer top margin must be set on auto -->
<app-footer class="mt-auto"></app-footer>
```